# How to disable responsive behaviour in Foundation 5

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation

Foundation 5 is toted as being **mobile-first**, but for a web-app that is desktop-only I need to disable the responsive behaviour that kicks in when shrinking the viewport size.

We're currently using a very minimal grid-only Foundation setup without much customisation.

Is there a way to set a specific app width without having to get the Foundation _settings.scss file to alter the @media queries, as suggested in [this](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/11447-disable-the-responsive-feature-foundation-5) post?

Comment: You could copy the rendered stylesheet, modify the media queries, and load the copy after the original. Not very clean, but it should work. Why can't you do the proper fix?

Comment: This should do it for you: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use the grid, the easy way to disable responsiveness is to remove the Viewport tag in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

And then after Foundation is called in the SCSS or CSS, .row will need to be set to a fixed width rather than max-width:

```
.row {max-width:none; width:960px;}
```